# Missing Argument 2 for apply_filter

Tags: filters

### Note

- WP_DEBUG set false
- NO arguments used in function.

  `function wpse203948_header_cart(){
      $cart = class_exists('WooCommerce') ? WC()->cart->get_cart_url() : '';
      if(!empty($cart)){
          ?>
              <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $cart ); ?>" class="header-cart dropdown-toggle"><i class="pe-7s-cart"><span><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span></i></a>
          <?php
      }
  }
  add_filter( 'wpse203948_header_cart', 'wpse203948_header_cart', 10, 1 );`

  //applying it

  `apply_filters( 'wpse203948_header_cart' );`

But I am getting `Missing Argument 2 for apply_filter` warning.

Comment: WHAT is `wpse203948_header_cart` in this world?

Answer (score 6):

You're not filtering anything, that's what's missing and what the error is complaining about. Filters accept an input value and return something.

```
$original_value = 'foo';
$filtered_value = apply_filters( 'wpd_filter_function', $original_value );
```

The function should then accept `$original_value` as an argument and `return` some value, which is what you'll get in `$filtered_value`.

What you have in your code would be more appropriate as an action:

```
function wpse203948_header_cart(){
    echo 'something';
}
add_action( 'wpse203948_header_cart', 'wpse203948_header_cart' );

// applying it
do_action( 'wpse203948_header_cart' );
```